# MySQL Combine Row Values

Tags: mysql

Forgive my ignorance of MySQL terminology I'm sure there is a better way to ask this...

I'm looking for a way to Query a table in a terribly designed database I inherited of several 100 thousand rows and reduce the results as per my example below adding together the values of the projectcost field for each row that has the same value listed in the companyname field.

Example of the table:

```
companyname  projectcost  typeofproject
company1     1000          network
company1     2000          network
company1     500           servers
company2     1000          network
company2     500           network
company2     500           security
```

I would like to be able to get the total costs per company per project like this:

`companyname  projectcost  typeofproject
company1     3000          network
company1     500           servers
company2     1500          network
company2     500           security`

and like this:

`companyname  projectcost
company1     3500
company2     2000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a simple **GROUP BY** clause by the columns you want to group (**companyname** and **typeofproject**), and then using the **SUM()** aggregate method over the **projectcost** column.

For the first query you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    companyname,
    typeofproject,
    SUM(projectcost)
FROM
    <table_name>
GROUP BY
    companyname, typeofproject
```

For the second query, this will do it:

```
SELECT
    companyname,
    SUM(projectcost)
FROM
    <table_name>
GROUP BY
    companyname
```

Comment: Thank You D. Smania.  "Grouping" is the term I'm looking for...